# A question about F-signature

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$ is any local ring of dimension $d$ and characteristic $p>0.$ In the first paragraph of [Corollary 3.5](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.4173.pdf) :

Let us first reduce to the case where $R$ is $F$-finite. After picking a coefficient field for $\widehat{R}$ and generators $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ for $\mathfrak{m},$ let $(S,\mathfrak{n},l)$ be the complete faithfully flat local ring extension of $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$ with $\mathfrak{m}S=\mathfrak{n}$ and $l=l^{p}$ given by
\begin{align}
R\longrightarrow\widehat{R}\longrightarrow\color{blue}{\widehat{R}\otimes_{k[[T_{1},...,T_{n}]]}k^{\infty}[[T_{1},...,T_{n}]]=:S} 
\end{align}
where $k[[T_{1},...,T_{n}]]\twoheadrightarrow\widehat{R}$ maps $T_{i}\mapsto x_{i}$ and $l=k^{\infty}$ is a perfect closure of $k.$

I am thinking about maybe a kind of stupid question that why $S$ should be complete although I know that $\widehat{R}$ and $k^{\infty}[[T_{1},...,T_{n}]]$ are both complete.  I will be grateful if someone can give me any hints or suggestions.

Comment: I think the reason is that $k[[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]]\rightarrow \widehat{R}$ is surjective, so $S$ is a quotient of the complete noetherian ring $k^\infty[[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]]$ and thus complete itself.